# Django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL changes does not affect behavior

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-settings

The login redirect URL was set to the `dashboard` since now when I have tried to change it to `all-records`. I have noticed that no matter what URL I put there, it will redirect to the dashboard. Even if I delete the line it redirects to `dashboard`. I am using Django debug toolbar and the settings file is saved and updated correctly. How do I fix this?

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'all-records'
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('all-records/<str:filter>',
         views.TbEntranceRightListView.as_view(), name='all-records'),
   
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forget place /Some/:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/all-records/'
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying pass a app name, you need pass a url:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/" # exemple first page
```

when you set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL as 'dashboard', that worked because your app and you url have a same name, and for access the app "all-records" you need a variable together